cannot connect to mongodb ETIMEOUT
Since i change my network i cannot connect to MongoDB. i have been searching for a solution in here, most of it says that i need to change my DNS. i have change my DNS to 8.8.8.8 but i still cant connect.
the error says:
Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT clusterIventory.xcndkot.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:188:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'clusterta.xcndkot.mongodb.net'
}

i also have change connection string from
const uri = "mongodb+srv://bryantpirih:<password>@clusterInventory.xcndkot.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(uri, { 
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
.then(() => {
  console.log("MongoDB Connected")
})
.catch(err=> console.log(err))

to the latest
const uri = "mongodb+srv://bryantpirih:<password>@clusterInventory.xcndkot.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=ClusterTA";
mongoose.connect(uri, { 
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
.then(() => {
  console.log("MongoDB Connected")
})
.catch(err=> console.log(err))

im expecting to to connect to MongoDB any solutions?

You need to white-list your IP

@WernfriedDomscheit sorry i forgot to mention that. but i already tried to white-list my IP as well but i still cant connect. ty for the help

Maybe your network firewall/proxy server blocks it.

queryTxt is a DNS TXT call. Th resolution needs to be resolved before the timeout. Check if you have a slow DNS server or using a network that doesn't allow DNS TXT results through. Use nslookup -type=TXT clusterInventory.xcndkot.mongodb.net
Make sure clusterInventory.xcndkot.mongodb.net is the right hostname.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
